# Dubai International Airport - Terminal 2 to Terminal 3?

Tags: visas

Do I need a visa to transfer between Terminal 2 and 3 in Dubai International Airport? Is transport available?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can stay airside.  There are trains and walkways underneath the terminals that will whisk you from T2 to T3. (source: have done this).  I believe there is also a transfer bus, but that it's intermittent.

If in doubt on where to go, when you arrive ask at the Transfer Desk.